# ABPersonViewController "add to favorites" action strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I'm using `ABPersonViewController` to show contact info. I want to allow user to perform standard actions, like `Text message`, `Share contact`, `Add to favorites`.

When I tap `Add to favorites`, near the contact's phone becomes blue star - so, it seems like contact is added to favorites. But in native Phone app in `favorites` there is no my contact's phone. Also strangely is that when I relaunch my app and browse the same contact, blue star still showing.

I tried to save address book on back action and app going to background, but no result. `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate`'s `shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson` method is not firing on `Add to favorites` - I don't understand why, because on tapping `Text message` or `Share contact` it is firing.

So, what I'm doing wrong? Have you any ideas how to make `Add to favorites` action work properly?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not saving changes to the address book. There are some methods related to the Address Book management like `ABAddressBookSave` or `ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges`.

You have all the information in the related Apple Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookSave).